# Check if the first css file of a link tag exists in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is used to refresh the current page if the first `<link />` could not be opened or if it has changed path.

Old path: `/v1/css/main.min.1614693445663.css`
New path: `/v1/css/main.min.16146934488888.css`

This is due to a cache problem in order to avoid losing the user.

```js
// refresh if the client (in nodejs) does not find the first css file because of an old cache for example
$.ajax({
  url: $("link[rel='stylesheet']").attr('href'), //This can be the first <link of the page
  type: 'HEAD',
  error: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.location.reload();
    }, 3000);
    //file not exists
  },
  success: function() {
    //file exists
  }
});
```

How to convert this Jquery code into pure JavaScript?

Comment: While what you're trying to do may well be possible through client-side JS, why not set caching rules on your CSS on the server side (ie. via headers, not the actual filename) to avoid the issue in the first place?

Comment: Please don’t ask us to rewrite this from jQuery to plain JS for you. This is a very basic AJAX request, and how those work in plain JS, you can go read up on yourself. Make a proper attempt, and if you run into trouble with that, then show us what you tried - then we can try and help you figure out, what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content page:

`<link href="/v1/css/main.min.1614781878390.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

New code:

```
// refresh if the client does not find the first css file
var qs = document.querySelector("link[rel='stylesheet']");
var MrChecker = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  CheckThisUrl = qs.getAttribute('href');
  
MrChecker.open('get', CheckThisUrl, true);
MrChecker.onreadystatechange = checkReadyState;


function checkReadyState() {
  if (MrChecker.readyState === 4) {
    if ((MrChecker.status == 200) || (MrChecker.status == 0)) {
      //alert(CheckThisUrl + ' page is exixts');
    }
    else {
      //alert(CheckThisUrl + ' not exists');
      setTimeout(function(){document.location.reload();}, 2000);
      return;
    }
  }
}

MrChecker.send(null);
```

I got there, I was inspired by https://jsfiddle.net/pu3antasyah/v95Loyvu/